# Linq Left Join on the table which have a higher number of records

Tags: linq

I have two data sources say :

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and populated with some data as :

```
 var data1 = new List<Person>() { new Person() { Id = 1, Name = "data 11" }, new Person() { Id = 2, Name = "data 12" } };

 var data2 = new List<Employee>() { new Employee() { Id = 1, Name = "data 21" }, new Employee() { Id = 2, Name = "data 22" }, new Employee() { Id = 3, Name = "data 23" } };
```

I have created query to make Left Join as :

```
    var query = (from person in (data1)
                        join employee in (data2) on person.Id equals employee.Id
                            into temp
                        from y in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new { Data = y }).ToList();
```

Now my Question is :
-- I want to make Parent or "from source" the one datasource which has higher Count.

**Scenario is like**  : if data1.Count > data2.Count THEN :
same as above query

if data2.Count > data1.Count THEN :

```
                      var query =  (from employee in (data2)
                        join person in (data1) on employee.Id equals                       
                         person.Id
                            into temp
                        from y in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new { Data = y }).ToList();
```

How can I achieve this since Linq does not provide out of the box Right Join in Linq ?
Please guide.

Comment: count the length first and then detemine the query.

Comment: yes that is certainly one way of doing, but I was looking for some generic solution if available.

Comment: LINQ provides a way to query a collection in a SQL like way.Not an approach of counting collections and perform joins. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can define an interface that both entities implement, then you can write the query generically based on this interface:

```
  interface INameIdPair {
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
  }

  public class Person : INameIdPair {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }

  public class Employee : INameIdPair {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }

  var data1 = new List<INameIdPair> {
    new Person { Id = 1, Name = "data 11" },
    new Person { Id = 2, Name = "data 12" }
  };

  var data2 = new List<INameIdPair> {
    new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "data 21" },
    new Employee { Id = 2, Name = "data 22" },
    new Employee { Id = 3, Name = "data 23" }
  };

  var from1 = data1.Count > data2.Count ? data1 : data2;
  var from2 = from1 == data1 ? data2 : data1;

  var query =
    (from ff1 in from1
      join ff2 in from2 on ff1.Id equals ff2.Id
        into temp
      from y in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
      select new {Data = y}
      ).ToList();
```

Comment: ummmh...That will work great here. But I have complex data structure and both Models are having different properties. It will still work though.

Comment: @AnkurMore In general, you should be able to define an interface so that you can express the join condition. That will allow to switch the 2 data sources based on the number of record and express the query generically. You may need to define another interface  or use dynamic objects (ExpandoObject) to express the result.

Comment: Thanks HashPsi for your suggestions.